# flyway 3.2 Unable to scan for SQL migrations in filesystem location

Tags: sql, filesystems, location, flyway

I am executing the oracle 11g sql scripts using flyway 3.2 from command line.

```
flyway -X -locations=filesystem:/flyway/ProjectA/sql -configFile=flyway.conf.ProjectA migrate
```

> ERROR: Unexpected error org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable
>   to scan for SQL migrations in location:
>   filesystem:/flyway/ProjectA/sql
>
> Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid filesystem
>   path: /flyway/ProjectA/sql

Any thoughts or work around to override the default /sql folder (similar to configuration files) using command line tool.

Comment: Does that path exists on disk? Does it contains at least one migration file following the naming convention?

Comment: well, I think it needs completed path. The following worked for me

Comment: flyway -X -locations=filesystem:/home/userA/flyway/ProjectA/sql -configFile=flyway.conf.ProjectA migrate

Comment: @pavan You should submit that as an answer. It worked for me.